# Rsync like program for Windows 7

Tags: windows, linux, file-management, backup, file-synchronization

I use Rsync with my linux machines to back up files across drives.

I am now trying to help a friend come up with a solution to easily backup files across drives, on his Windows 7 machine.

What is the windows world equivalent to Rsync (doesn't neccesarily have to be command line utility).

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Aside from the Cygwin package mentioned by Kodiologist (and by extension one for [MobaXterm](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/)), there's also [cwRsync](https://www.itefix.net/cwrsync), and [Grsync](http://www.opbyte.it/grsync/) )which also works as a GUI for rsync on UNIX systems too).

You could also just build rsync yourself locally.  Last I checked, it builds and links fine for Windows using mingw.

Answer (score 1):

I used the following two

**Delta Copy**
http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp

> Incremental backup - Copies part of the file that is actually modified
>   Task scheduler - Profiles in DeltaCopy can run based on a schedule
>   Email notification - Administrators can receive email confirmation on
>   successful as well as failed transfers One-click restore - Backed up
>   files can be easily restored. Windows friendly environment - No need
>   to manually modify configuration files or play around with command
>   line options.

It's based on Windows service

**cwRsync** https://itefix.net/cwrsync

> It's more advanced tool. cwRsync is a packaging of Rsync (link is
>   external) for Windows with a client GUI. You can use cwRsync for fast
>   remote file backup and synchronization.
>
> cwRsync - Rsync for WindowsRsync uses the Rsync algorithm (link is
>   external) which provides a very fast method for bringing remote files
>   into sync. It does this by sending just the differences in the files
>   across the link, without requiring that both sets of files are present
>   at one of the ends of the link beforehand. At first glance this may
>   seem impossible because the calculation of diffs between two files
>   normally requires local access to both files.
>
> Rsync normally uses ssh for communication. It requires no special
>   privileges for installation. You must, however, have a working ssh
>   system. Alternatively, rsync can run in `daemon' mode, listening on a
>   socket. This is generally used for public file distribution, although
>   authentication and access control are available.

For very simple sync tasks I would also recommend [SyncToy](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15155) from Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

[Cygwin's](https://www.cygwin.com/) built-in package manager has a package for rsync.